# Al teclear en un campo de Java Swing el término de búsqueda, demora mucho tiempo en realizar la consulta a la base de datos y se cuelga el programa

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy haciendo un software en Java sin ningún framework y estoy usando Java Swing para la interfaz gráfica y MySQL para la base de datos. Se me dio por hacer una prueba de agregar 300 productos a mi tabla de *tb_productos* para ver como reaccionaba el programa. Cuando voy a probar ya para abrir un internalFrame con una tabla de los productos tardo demasiado: tengo un textfield para hacer búsqueda, cuando tecleo para hacer las búsquedas se tilda y tarda muchísimo. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Dejo un pedazo del código donde lleno la tabla de productos.

```
private void CargarTablaProducto(String busquedad) {

    Ctrl_Proveedor ctrlProveedor = new Ctrl_Proveedor();

    Connection cn = Conexion.conectar();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_producto WHERE estado = 1";

    if ((busquedad.equals("") || busquedad.isEmpty()) && jRadioButton1.isSelected() == false && jRadioButton2.isSelected() == false) {
        sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_producto WHERE estado = 1";
    } else if ((busquedad.equals("") || busquedad.isEmpty()) && jRadioButton1.isSelected() == true && jRadioButton2.isSelected() == false) {
        sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_producto WHERE estado = 0";
    } else if (jRadioButton2.isSelected()) {
        if (jRadioButton1.isSelected() == false) {
            sql = "SELECT p.* FROM tb_producto p JOIN tb_proveedor pr ON p.idProveedor = pr.idProveedor WHERE pr.descripcion LIKE '%" + busquedad + "%' AND p.estado = 1";
        } else if (jRadioButton1.isSelected() == true) {
            sql = "SELECT p.* FROM tb_producto p JOIN tb_proveedor pr ON p.idProveedor = pr.idProveedor WHERE pr.descripcion LIKE '%" + busquedad + "%' AND p.estado = 0";
        }
    } else {
        if (jRadioButton1.isSelected() == false) {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_producto WHERE (idProducto LIKE '%" + busquedad + "%' OR nombre LIKE '%" + busquedad + "%') AND estado = 1";
        } else if (jRadioButton1.isSelected() == true) {
            sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_producto WHERE (idProducto LIKE '%" + busquedad + "%' OR nombre LIKE '%" + busquedad + "%') AND estado = 0";
        }
    }

    Statement st;

    try {
        st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            Object fila[] = new Object[8];

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                if (i == 3 || i == 4 || i == 7) {
                    fila[i] = "$ " + rs.getObject(i + 1);
                } else if (i == 5) {
                    fila[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1) + " %";
                } else if (i == 6) {
                    Proveedor proveedor = ctrlProveedor.proveedorPorID((int) rs.getObject(i + 1));
                    fila[i] = proveedor.getDescripcion();
                } else {
                    fila[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
                }
            }

            model.addRow(fila);
        }

        cn.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error al llenar la tabla Producto: " + e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Con 300 registro debería volar, yo dudo que tu problema esté en la consulta. Te recomiendo medir los tiempos entre funcionalidades con algo como `System.nanoTime()`. Mides lo que se demora la consulta, lo que demora procesarla y lo que demora en cargarla en pantalla y ve cual es el real cuello de botella

Comment: Si haces la misma consulta desde otro cliente de MySQL (ej. Workbench, phpMyAdmin) ¿Tarda lo mismo?

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, muchas gracias por responder. Lo que demoraba era usar el metodo ctrlProveedor.proveedorPorID(int) que me devolvia un proveedor y yo de ahi le escribia el nombre, para que no me aparezca el ID. Lo resolvi haciendo un JOIN en la consulta.

Comment: @GregorioNuñez recuerda que el formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_. Si ya lo resolviste, ponlo como respuesta (en base a [answer]), y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Por cierto, ¡no agregues etiquetas que no corresponden! [jquery] nada tiene que ver con tu pregunta.